# Making a Flow union type of strings from properties in a union type of objects

Tags: flowtype

I have a union type of object types like:

```
type Action = { type: 'A' } | { type: 'B' } | { type: 'C' } // and so on
```

I want to make a union type of their type properties, like:

```
type ActionType = 'A' | 'B' | 'C' // and so on
```

Is there a way to do this programmatically in Flow (i.e. so I don't have to manually list out all the string literals to make `ActionType`)? I couldn't figure it out using `$ObjMap`, `$PropertyType`, `$Call`, or any combination thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$PropertyType`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype) and [`$ElementType`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) both work here.

```
type ActionType = $PropertyType<Action, "type">;
// OR
type ActionType = $ElementType<Action, "type">;
```